# How to convert column header style from horizontal to vertical in pandas dataframe having multiindex?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Below is the my current multiindex column header

[image]

I want it to be displayed like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cant try modifying the HTML style of the dataframe, try adjusting the hegiht property:

```
styles = [dict(
     selector="th.col_heading.level1",
     props=[("transform", "rotate(270deg);"),
            ("height", "100px")]
)]
      
df.style.set_table_styles(styles)
```

Answer (score 0):

May not  answer  the original 'multiindex' question but useful for formatting header row and display precision when using table_style

```
def mdf_format_vertical_headers(df,height_str='100px',transform_str='rotate(-90deg)',precision=3):
"""Display a dataframe with vertical column headers. Returns a styler object - Only affects display so cant use .head() etc
rotate(-90deg) - rotates the text by 90 degrees. default. TBD why negative numbers
rotate(-80deg) - rotates the text by 80 degrees

"""
styles = [dict(selector="th", props=[('width', '40px')]),
          dict(selector="th.col_heading",
               props=[("writing-mode", "horizontal"),
                      ('transform',transform_str ), 
                      ('height', height_str),
                      ('vertical-align', 'top')])]
 
return (df.fillna('').style.set_table_styles(styles).format(precision=precision))
```